# Is it possible to control 'cursor' of console output / add offset to stdout without overwriting the characters occupying the offset?

Tags: python, io, console, ascii, stdout

### Main Problem...

I'm wondering (hoping) there's a way to manage console output to allow advanced printing utility.

Specifically, I'm wondering if there's a way to move the 'cursor' of where the next character will be printed to the next character space, without overwriting the character that is in the space skipped.

I'm hoping there's a solution that doesn't involve installing new modules or tracking stdout history.

### Inspiration - The Carriage Return Character

I know the carriage return character ('\r') can be used to move the 'cursor' of console output back to the beginning of the line.

From there, I know you can print whatever you want to overwrite as many characters as you put in stdout, leaving the leftover characters from previous output.

However, I'd like to leave x-amount of characters from previous characters on the left, and then write my output, overwriting as necessary, for the rest of my line.

### For example...

I'd like to print output:

```
_____|    Name   |    Desc    |    Task    |    Progress    |
 [1]  Foo         Bar          BarFoo       [====    ] 50.0%
```

And then be able to update the second line, without knowing that name is "Foo" and desc is "Bar", to have "FooBar" under task (and update progress bar...)

```
_____|    Name   |    Desc    |    Task    |    Progress    |
 [1]  Foo         Bar          FooBar       [=====   ] 62.5%
```

That is, I want to modify characters shown below with █ while maintaining characters shown below as X

```
_____|    Name   |    Desc    |    Task    |    Progress    |
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX██████XXXXXXXX████████XX█████X
```

### I know that I can avoid this problem...

If I settle for having the dynamic line content on the left and the static content on the right, I can safely update the line without losing the static content as long as the width of the dynamic content is known/limited in advance.
I don't want this for styling reasons.

I know I can set up some system to keep track of what has already been printed, and reprint it to maintain the static content.
I don't want this because what I'm working on has a lot of concurrency and it would be tedious to do, for a graphical effect.

I'm also just curious if this kind of function is supported.

### Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cursor arbitrarily by printing special escape sequences. See  [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) for a reference.

Comment: This would be exactly what I'm looking for, except I don't think it is supported in either of the terminals I'm using. Do you by any chance know where I can find more information about where this is supported?

Comment: @136 No, sorry, but I'm sure Google has an answer for you there. But make sure to check first tough, since you said you "think" it's not supported. Every terminal I've tried this works for...